# "Verify that your firewall or antivirus allows Python processes to open ports in your siystem" Spyder problem

Tags: python, spyder, firewall

I have a problem when opening Spyder (Python 3.7), i get a warning saying code completion and linting will not work. I'm sure it's not the antivirus and i have given python the OK through the Windows Firewall settings (I don't really know if i did the right thing, just checked the two boxes to let it connect to networks). Restarting Spyder doesn't solve the issue. I'm a noob so i was hoping someone could help me, thanks.

[Warning i get every-time I open Spyder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuSWP.png)

Comment: You allpwed spyder through the firewall but not other python processes that require internet.

Comment: Did you install Spyder with anaconda, pip or the standalone installer? In case of anaconda you could try to reset your preferences (for that run from an Anaconda Prompt, under the env you are using Spyder, the command `spyder --reset`)